# Why is “remove to” no longer used?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences

By [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference%20between%20move%20and%20remove&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS770US770&oq=difference%20between%20move%20and%20remove&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.14924j1j7&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), the difference between **remove** and **move** can be found as follows:

As verbs the difference between **remove** and **move**
is that **remove** is to move something from one place to another, especially to take away while **move** is to change place or posture; to stir; to go, in any manner, from one place or position to another.

I question why I don’t hear **remove to** while it is defined as *to take something from one place **to** another?*

- [**remove to** in Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remove%20to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cremove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bremove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRemove%20to%3B%2Cc0)
- [**remove to** vs **move to** in
  Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remove%20to%2C%20move%20to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cremove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bremove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRemove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmove%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMove%20to%3B%2Cc0)

I *thonked* a line that said “**Remove my soul to Luca’s body!**” (Think of it as a *spell* or *command* in a *fantasy* writing) and I’m sure that the sentence means “*Take my soul out of my body and place it in Luca’s body!”*
I just wondered why I shouldn’t say it.

Comment: We refer to the business of moving people's belongings from one house to another as _removals_, but no-one says "I'm removing to Manchester next week". Dictionaries seem to describe that sense of the word as 'dated' or 'formal'.

Comment: Yes, and my question is why it’s dated.

Comment: I've heard *I'm removing it to* used before. It's just not at all common. Asking *why* something is no longer said is very often a futile question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does my example, “Remove my soul to Luca’s body!” make sense to you at all?